# make a column with dynamic hyperlink using Juery plguin datatable

Tags: hyperlink, datatable

I would like to make my Site_ID column with hyperlink, when click the each Site_ID, it will links to different pages. below is my code, can anyone give me some suggestions?

```
    var infoTable = $('#resultTable').dataTable({
        "processing"  : true,
        "serverSide"  : true,
        "scrollX"     : true,
        "jQueryUI"    : true,
        "deferRender" : true,
        "order"       : [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "ajax": "./DataTables-1.10.15/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php",                
        "pagingType"  : "full_numbers",
        "oLanguage"   : {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
        "aoColumns":[
            {
                "data":"Site_ID",
                "render": function ( data,type,full, meta ) {
                  return '<a href="'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';                             
                }
            },
            ]
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it's running well.

var infoTable = $('#resultTable').dataTable({
            "processing"  : true,
            "serverSide"  : true,
            "scrollX"     : true,
            "jQueryUI"    : true,
            "deferRender" : true,
            "order"       : [[ 0, "asc" ]],
            "ajax": "./DataTables-1.10.15/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php",
            "pagingType"  : "full_numbers",
            "oLanguage"   : {
                "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
            },
            columnDefs : [
                { targets : [0],
                  render : function(data) {
                    return ''+data+''
                  } 
                }
              ]
          });